# Is it possible to render image with html?

Tags: html

I have control in a page that gets html from text file and renders that html in webpage.
Right now it has to add image somewhere and reference that image src.

I was wondering if we can render image along with other html code, is it possible?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, it is. You need a [Data URI scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme):

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,
iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAAKCAYAAACNMs+9AAAABGdBTUEAALGP
C/xhBQAAAAlwSFlzAAALEwAACxMBAJqcGAAAAAd0SU1FB9YGARc5KB0XV+IA
AAAddEVYdENvbW1lbnQAQ3JlYXRlZCB3aXRoIFRoZSBHSU1Q72QlbgAAAF1J
REFUGNO9zL0NglAAxPEfdLTs4BZM4DIO4C7OwQg2JoQ9LE1exdlYvBBeZ7jq
ch9//q1uH4TLzw4d6+ErXMMcXuHWxId3KOETnnXXV6MJpcq2MLaI97CER3N0
vr4MkhoXe0rZigAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==" alt="Red dot" />
```

The same can be done in CSS:

```
ul.checklist > li.complete { margin-left: 20px; background:
  url('data:image/png;base64,
iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABAAAAAQAQMAAAAlPW0iAAA
ABlBMVEUAAAD///+l2Z/dAAAAM0lEQVR4nGP4/5/h/1+G/5
8ZDrAz3D/McH8yw83NDDeNGe4Ug9C9zwz3gVLMDA/A6P9/A
FGGFyjOXZtQAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC') top left no-repeat; }
```

Comment: Note that only very recent versions of IE support data URIs.

Answer (score 3):

You can use inline [SVG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SVG). See this [article for mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/SVG_In_HTML_Introduction) and this [one for IE](http://intertwingly.net/blog/2007/05/04/Inline-SVG-in-MSIE).

Answer (score 2):

You can also create images using CSS and different size characters and playing with z-indexes. Here's [CSS Homer](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/200805/css_homer_animated.html).

Answer (score 1):

I've seen it done by creating a table with one cell for each pixel, setting the cell's background color to the pixel's color.

Comment: Note that while this is possible, it is a hack and tends to make browsers crawl as they deal with a huge DOM.

Comment: As an office joke several months ago I wrote a python script to do exactly this.  You're welcome to mess around with it but as David pointed out it produces huge amounts of HTML that slow down the browsers.  In my testing anything over about 3.5MB of HTML will crash a browser which is an image about the size of 500x500.  https://gist.github.com/705023