# How/is it possible to embed an image created with libgd directly into an html img tag?

Tags: php

I'm trying to create an image with the php libgd library and use the variable that is being used to store the image info to embed the image on a page.

e.g.

```
$image = get_image();

function get_image() {
    $image = imagecreate(...);
    ...
    return $image;
}

//echo '<img src="'.$image.'"/>';
```

Hopefully you get what I'm trying to do.. I know I can create a separate .php file that could be used like:

```
echo '<img src="image.php"/>';
```

where image.php is..

```
<?php
    $image = get_image();
    header('Content-Type: image/png');
    imagepng($image);
    imagedestroy($image);
?>
```

Is there anyway to avoid doing the second example, i.e. what I tried to explain the first time?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to render image with html?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/955076/is-it-possible-to-render-image-with-html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way you could do something similar is with a [data URI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme).  However, cross-browser support is very mixed, so it's probably not an option yet.

Your best bet is probably an appropriate caching scheme in the filesystem.  This also has performance benefits, since you don't need to generate the image every time.

If you do go the data URI route, you can output the base64 part like this:

```
ob_start();
imagepng($image);
$image_str = ob_get_clean();
echo base64_encode($image_str);
```

Comment: I looked into your suggestion using data URIs and I quickly ran into the same problem the poster on this forum was having (http://forums.devshed.com/php-development-5/inline-images-in-img-tag--how-can-i-base64-encode-234459.html). PHP resources can't be converted to base64 strings. I was trying to avoid using temporary files, do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: I posted how to do that conversion.